# Clipping a raster layer with a shapefile on mac

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, clip, mac

I am trying to clip a raster layer using the raster clipper function. 
However, for some reason this is not working for me and I haven't been able to find the answer anywhere.

I choose my raster layer as the input file, my shapefile as the mask layer and creates an output file, but after pressing OK nothing happens.

I am using QGIS 2.6.0 and following the steps presented at: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/raster_mosaicing_and_clipping.html

Does anybody have an idea of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure both layers have the same CRS, and the extents match without OTF-reprojection too?

Comment: I have already checked this and CRS is correct. Maybe my best shot is to update QGIS and see if that helps. 
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you've followed all the steps except one, that is ticking the"Add layer to canvas" box.
Check in the directory where you stored your new layer, it might be there. Alternatively, try to add the layer you've just created and see what happens. 
I hope this was of some help.
Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) 
But it's unfortunately not that simple, because i have already ticked the "Add layer to canvas". 
When I press OK it processes for two seconds, but it doesn't save any new layer in the destination folder or add a layer in QGIS. 
I think I twill try to update QGIS and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that Mac is not working properly when combining vector with raster data. Raster calculations is not a problem but vector and raster is an issue. Sometimes it simply takes a lot of time and calculations are done. In other cases it does not work.

Comment: You can try Raster - Extraction - Clipper. Maybe that works. Within the CSP tool you can also clip (satellite images) but there it did not work in my case.